# Clip not playing any sound

Tags: java, audio, javasound

Well, the title says all, I tried playing a wav file using javax.sound and nothing is happening. I have tried many different files without any luck.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException
{

    File in = new File("C:\\Users\\Sandra\\Desktop\\music\\rags.wav");
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
    Clip play = AudioSystem.getClip();
    play.open(audioInputStream);
    FloatControl volume= (FloatControl) play.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
    volume.setValue(1.0f); // Reduce volume by 10 decibels.
    play.start();

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or is just nothing happening?

Comment: for working examples take a look http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info

Answer (score 8):

As, has already begin stated, you need to prevent the main thread from exiting, as this will cause the JVM to terminate.

`Clip#start` is not a blocking call, meaning that it will return (soon) after it is called.

I have no doubt that there are many ways to approach this problem and this is just a simple example of one of them.

```
public class PlayMusic {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Clip play = null;
        try {
            File in = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Music\\Sample Music\\Kalimba.wav");
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
            play = AudioSystem.getClip();
            play.open(audioInputStream);
            FloatControl volume = (FloatControl) play.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
            volume.setValue(1.0f); // Reduce volume by 10 decibels.
            play.start();
            // Loop until the Clip is not longer running.
            // We loop this way to allow the line to fill, otherwise isRunning will
            // return false
            //do {
            //    Thread.sleep(15);
            //} while (play.isRunning());
            play.drain();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                play.close();
            } catch (Exception exp) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println("...");
    }
}
```

The actual solution will depend on your needs.

Comment: You have to appreciate blind downvoting without the simple cortesrty to explain why, so we all can learn what would make an answer better

Comment: @MadProgrammer `Clip` is a `DataLine` and as such, `start()` is non-blocking.  However, it's explicitly stated in the interface that the method `drain()` _is_ blocking: _"This method blocks until the draining is complete."_ from [DataLine.drain()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#drain()).

Any solution which requires artificially stalling the program from exiting is incorrect.  This is explicitly explained in the [Java Playing Back Audio Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html).

Comment: @Jared Hmm, good to know - also, very every rule, there's an excepiton ;)

Comment: I've done some tests on (1) laptop (Linux Mint 18.0 64bit) with JDK 1.8.0_102-b14 64bit) and (2) an Orange Pi Zero running Armbian 5.25 (kernel 3.4.113) with JDK 1.8.0_121-b13 (from Oracle). I have found that on (2)-OrPi `drain()` seems to be **not blocking**, but doing a `System.out.println(...)` ("peasant debugging") before it makes it blocking. Unfortunately, on (1)-laptop it is just the other way around, the `println(...)` makes it **not blocking** were it was blocking without it. Most reliable way on (1) and (2) was to `Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000)` - heh, uggggly...

Comment: @fr13d Have to say I'm not a fan of `drain`, I prefer to use a `LineListener`, if you need to, you could then use a `ReentrantLock` or something to single the end of the clip

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks. I have found that a `LineListener` that unblocks the main thread (done via `Object.wait()`/`Object.notify()` and also `Thread.join()`/`Thread.interrupt()`), causes an annoying "blip" sound at the end of playback on the Orange Pi (but not on the laptop).The `Thread.sleep()` technique still seems to function the best cross-platform (for my two platforms)...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I haven't looked at this in 7 years, but my god, if you preferred LineListestener, why not update your answer?

Comment: @fr13d You're doing it wrong, that's why you're having problems. Of course pausing your playback until it fully plays always works--you're not having a correct solution to your problem....and drain absolutely works--I'm also sure [LineListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/LineListener.html) does as well...you're not using them properly.

Answer (score 4):

Java's sound `Clip` requires an active `Thread` to play the audio input file otherwise the application exits before the file can be played. You could add

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Click OK to stop music");
```

after calling `start`.

Comment: `Clip` is a `DataLine` and as such, `start()` is non-blocking.  However, it's explicitly stated in the interface that the method `drain()` _is_ blocking: _"This method blocks until the draining is complete."_ from [DataLine.drain()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#drain()).

Any solution which requires artificially stalling the program from exiting is incorrect.  This is explicitly explained in the [Java Playing Back Audio Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html).

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to play the audio clip is to drain the line as explained in [Playing Back Audio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html).

So your main should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
    UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException
{
    File in = new File("C:\\Users\\Sandra\\Desktop\\music\\rags.wav");
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
    Clip play = AudioSystem.getClip();
    play.open(audioInputStream);
    FloatControl volume= (FloatControl) play.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
    volume.setValue(1.0f); // Reduce volume by 10 decibels.
    play.start();
    play.drain();
    play.close();
}
```

`play.drain()` blocks until all the data is played.

Answer (score 2):

Here [playing a clip](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           File in = new File("C:\\Users\\Sandra\\Desktop\\music\\rags.wav");
           AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
           Clip play = AudioSystem.getClip();
           play.open(audioInputStream);
           FloatControl volume= (FloatControl)play.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
           volume.setValue(1.0f); // Reduce volume by 10 decibels.
           play.start();
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // A GUI element to prevent the Clip's daemon Thread
                    // from terminating at the end of the main()
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program is terminating before the sound has the time to be played. I would do `play.start();` in some threading way (`invokeLater`, ...), and also find a way to wait until the sound has finished (Reimeus suggested one).

A lead :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

          ...

          play.start();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Click OK to stop music");
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to play an audio, here's a way.

The `audioFileDirectory` String variable needs the correct path to your audio file, otherwise an exception will be thrown and the program won't run.

Example of having the right audio file directory in a project if using an IDE:

1. Make a folder inside `src` folder, e.g: "music" and put an audio file there
2. `audioFileDirectory = "/music/name_of_audio_file";`

The important part for an audio to play is that the main thread of the program needs somehow to be "alive", so the line

```
Thread.sleep(audio.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
```

is where the main thread is "alive", and the argument `audio.getMicrosecondLength()/1000` is the time that will be "alive", which is the whole length of the audio file.

```
public class AudioTest
{
    void playAudio() throws Exception
    {
        String audioFileDirectory = "your_audioFileDirectory";
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(audioFileDirectory);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bis);
        Clip audio = AudioSystem.getClip();
        audio.open(ais);
        audio.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        audio.start();
        Thread.sleep(audio.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
        audio.close();
    } // end playAudio

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            new AudioTest().playAudio();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Class: " + e.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println("\nMessage:\n" + e.getMessage() + "\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // end main
} // end class AudioTest
```