# How to repeat audio file in java

Tags: java, audio

How would i get the audio file to repeat continuously? Right now the music just plays once and that;s it. I am trying to get the sound to repeat over and over. Would I have to get the audio file another way or is there a simpler way?

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

public class Sound {
    public static void music(String fileName) {
        try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
            AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How i call it:

```
// Plays the music.
public void music() {
    Sound.music("res/music/I Like Your Hat.wav");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't use `sun.*` packages, these are private packages and may not always be available. Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138614/clip-not-playing-any-sound/17139062#17139062) for some ideas on how to get a audio clip to play.
2. Take a look at [`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html) and [`Clip#loop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#loop(int))

As a very simple example...

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(...);
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioInputStream);
clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
clip.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the blind down vote, nice to know how this might be fixed