# Playing music in the background of a JFrame window

Tags: java, audio, jframe, audio-streaming

I am trying to play an audio file in the background of a Frame window and I'm finding out it is way more complicated then just adding a picture.

I found a "tutorial" that should how to add music and it seemed fairly simple, at least in the amount of code required.  However, I am not able to play the audio file, it is saying two things...

1st - I was trying to play a audio file I copied to my java project and that was telling me it could not find that file or directory.

2nd - I gave the method a path to a audio file and it's telling me...

```
could not get audio input stream from input file
```

Please keep in mind I'm very new and this tutorial did not give a lot of help, so I do not know a lot of what this play method is actually doing.  I'd love to learn how to do this but everything I've seen is overly complicated for this project and I don't have the time to put in because it's not necessary just a little added flair is all.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!  I put stars around the code in question.

```
public MultiForm() {
    super("Multi Form Program");        
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    menu = new JComboBox(fileName);
    add(menu);

    /*How to add a background image to the Menu.
     * add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("MatrixPIC.png"))));
     */

    TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();
    menu.addItemListener(handler);  
}

public void matrixPanel() {

    TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();
    //Create a new window when "The Matrix" is clicked in the JCB
    newFrame = new JFrame();
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel2 = new JPanel();

    newFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    newFrame.setSize(500, 300);
    newFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(newFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      

    matrixQuote = new JLabel("<html><center>After this, there is no turning back. "
            + "<br><center>You take the blue pill—the story ends, you wake up "
            + "<br><center>in your bed and believe whatever you want to believe."
            + "<br><center>You take the red pill—you stay in Wonderland, and I show"
            + "<br><center>you how deep the rabbit hole goes. "
            + "<br><center>Remember: all I'm offering is the truth. Nothing more.</html>");

    panel.add(matrixQuote);
    newFrame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //Blue pill button and picture. 
    Icon bp = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Blue Pill.png"));
    bluePill = new JButton("Blue Pill", bp);
    panel2.add(bluePill);   
    bluePill.addActionListener(handler);

    //Red pill button and picture
    Icon rp = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Red Pill.png"));
    redPill = new JButton("Red Pill", rp);
    panel2.add(redPill);

    newFrame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);      
    newFrame.setVisible(true);
}

*********************************************************************************
public void play(String path, int delay, int numberOfLoops) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLoops; i++) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    File file = new File(path);
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
                    clip.start();
                    Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
*********************************************************************************        

private class TheHandler implements ItemListener, ActionListener{

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent IE) {
        //listen for an item to be selected.
        if(IE.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            Object selection = menu.getSelectedItem();

            if("The Matrix".equals(selection)) {
                matrixPanel();
            }
            else if("Another Option".equals(selection)) {   
            }
        }   
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent AE) {
        if(AE.getSource() == bluePill) {
            //Clear panels after button is clicked.
            newFrame.remove(panel);         
            newFrame.remove(panel2);
            newFrame.repaint();
    *********************************************************************************       
            play("/Users/SWD/Downloads/fail.mp3", 10, 30);
 *********************************************************************************  
            newFrame.setSize(600, 400);
            bpPanelLabel = new JPanel();
            bpLabel = new JLabel("<html><center>WELCOME TO THE BEGINING OF YOUR NEW LIFE!  " +
                     "<br><center>YOU'RE ABOUT TO SEE HOW DEEP THE RABBIT HOLE GOES!</html>");
            newFrame.add(bpLabel);
            newFrame.add(bpPanelLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            bpPanelPic = new JPanel();
            newFrame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("MatrixPIC.png"))));
            newFrame.add(bpPanelPic, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
            newFrame.validate();
        }


    }   
}


//Main method sets up the main JFrame with the menu
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MultiForm go = new MultiForm();
    go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    go.setSize(400, 200);
    go.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Java Audio doesn't support (all) mp3 encodings. If you have to play mp3's, have a look at the [JavaZoom's JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) API

Comment: I also tried a .wav which I thought I read it would play?

Comment: I'd get rid of Thread.sleep

Comment: For repeating audio, have a look [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643416/how-to-repeat-audio-file-in-java/27643431#27643431)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Java's Audio API doesn't support (all) mp3 encoding.  If you need to play mp3's then you should have a look at [JavaZoom's JLayer API](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html)
2. If the file you are trying to play is within the project's src (or the Jar file by extension), you need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` instead
3. `Clip` auto supports looping by itself, so you don't need to use a loop of your own, which could block the Event Dispatching Thread.
4. The `Thread`'s seem a little over kill IMHO and while you could still use one to add an artificial delay, I used a Swing `Timer` in my example, as it's just simpler :P

For example

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

public class JavaApplication5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaApplication5();
    }

    public JavaApplication5() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Clip clip = null;

        private JTextField audioFile;
        private JButton browse;
        private JSpinner loops;
        private JSpinner delay;
        private JFileChooser chooser;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(new JLabel("Audio File:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            audioFile = new JTextField(20);
            add(audioFile);

            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.gridx++;
            browse = new JButton("...");
            add(browse, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Loops: "), gbc);

            loops = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 100, 1));
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            add(loops, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Delay (seconds): "), gbc);

            delay = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 10, 1));
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            add(delay, gbc);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            JButton play = new JButton("Play");
            add(play, gbc);

            play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        play(
                                        audioFile.getText(),
                                        (int) delay.getValue(),
                                        (int) loops.getValue());
                    } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "<html>Failed to play audio file:</br>" + ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            });

            browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (chooser == null) {
                        chooser = new JFileChooser();
                        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
                        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
                        chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileFilter() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean accept(File f) {
                                System.out.println(f);
                                return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".wav");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public String getDescription() {
                                return "Wave Files (.wav)";
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(TestPane.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        File selected = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                        audioFile.setText(selected.getPath());
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        public void play(String path, int delay, int numberOfLoops) throws LineUnavailableException, IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
            if (clip != null) {
                clip.stop();
                clip = null;
            }

            if (delay > 0) {
                System.out.println("Start with delay");
                Timer timer = new Timer(delay * 1000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            play(path, numberOfLoops);
                        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException | IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "<html>Failed to play audio file:</br>" + ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                });
                timer.setRepeats(false);
                timer.start();
            } else {
                play(path, numberOfLoops);
            }
        }

        private void play(String path, int numberOfLoops) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, IOException {
            File file = new File(path);
            if (file.exists()) {
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
                clip.start();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mad, that's a little overkill for this silly program I'm creating haha.  But, it's a good example to help me learn how to play audio and I appreciate you taking the time to answer!