# How to use java.applet.AudioClip?

Tags: java, audio

I would like to ask you how to use the java.applet.AudioClip. I have tried to use it, but I could not figure out how to use it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138614/clip-not-playing-any-sound/17139062#17139062)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I implement the AudioClip class:

```
AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
```

Where url is the URL object that points to my sound file. You can get the URL object multiple ways, but I use this (because it always works for me):

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sound1.wav");
```

And then to play the sound, call the clip's play method on a new Thread:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        clip.play();
    }
}.start();
```

Here's an example of a Sound class you could use to play your audio clips:

```
public class Sound {

    public static final Sound[] sounds = {
        new Sound("sound1.wav"),
        new Sound("sound2.wav")
    };

    private AudioClip clip;

    private Sound(String name) {
        clip = Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(name));
    }

    public void play() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                clip.play();
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

Just define all of your sounds in the static Sound array, and call those when you need to use the sound:

```
//anywhere outside of the Sound class
//(will play "sound1.wav" in this example)
Sound.sounds[0].play();
```

Hope this helped you!