# Simple: Java how to use "isRunning" on an audio clip?

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, error-handling, clip

In java i need to check if an audio clip is running but when i try something like:

```
if(clip1.isRunning()){

}
```

Eclipse gives me the error of:

"The method isRunning() is undefined for the type AudioClip."

Do i have to add something to use isRunning() on an audioclip? or am i doing something wrong?

Due to it being a long program here is just my imports and me initializing the audioclip and the part where i use it:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.Timer;

AudioClip clip1;

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    if (xPos > 0 && xPos < 0+64 && yPos >0 &&  
            yPos < 0+64){
        if(soundMuted == false){
            soundMuted = true;
            clip1.stop();
        }
        else{
            if (clip1.isRunning()){

            }
            else{
                soundMuted = false;
                clip1.play();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the error i get:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method isRunning() is undefined for the type AudioClip  HomeScreen.java                
/AlexVega2/src  line 421    Java Problem
```

Comment: Have you imported `javax.sound.sampled.Clip`?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: can share little bit code ?

Comment: Yes i just imported it and i still get the same error.

Comment: AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("demo.wav"));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(inputStream);

Comment: There i added some of the code

Comment: @YogendraSharma can you explain a bit how would i implement that with the code i provided below vvvv

Comment: @MadProgrammer There i shared some of it vvvv

Comment: `java.applet.AudioClip` does not extend from any class which inherits from `javax.sound.sampled.Clip`, therefore, it does not have a `isRunning` method

Comment: It would be helpful to see more context into how you are using `Clip`.  Is it an applet or is it a desktop application window?

Comment: @MadProgrammer It is an applet.

Comment: @Intrinza Okay, do you need the `isRunning` method??

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, i really need to check if the audio is running or not.

Answer (score 0):

`java.applet.AudioClip` does not extend from any class which inherits from `javax.sound.sampled.Clip`, therefore, it does not have a `isRunning` method

To use `javax.sound.sampled.Clip`, you'll have to make use of the [Sound API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/), for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836255/playing-multiple-sound-clips-using-clip-objects/29836764#29836764) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138614/clip-not-playing-any-sound/17139062#17139062)

The audio clip for this example is expected to be embedded within the Jar file (and this example has them in the `sounds` package, but you can change to where ever you need it)

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test extends JApplet {

    private Clip clip;
    private JButton btnPlay;
    private JLabel label;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        btnPlay = new JButton("Bring the noise");
        label = new JLabel("___");

        add(btnPlay, gbc);
        add(label, gbc);

        btnPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                play();
            }
        });

        Timer timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
            private int counter = 0;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (clip == null || !clip.isRunning()) {
                    label.setText("___");
                } else {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("          ");
                    for (int index = 0; index < counter; index++) {
                        sb.setCharAt(index, '.');
                    }
                    label.setText(sb.toString());
                    counter++;
                    if (counter > 10) {
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }

    protected void play() {

        try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sounds/Maid with the Flaxen Hair.wav")) {
            try (AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is)) {
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void update(LineEvent event) {
                        System.out.println(event.getFramePosition());
                        if (event.getType().equals(LineEvent.Type.STOP)) {
                            btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
                clip.open(audioInputStream);
                clip.start();
                btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        super.stop();
        if (clip != null) {
            clip.stop();
        }
    }

}
```

Basically, when playing, this will animate the `JLabel` with a series if `.`, when it's no longer playing it will just be a `___` blank line

Comment: Could you give me a quick short example how i would change it? because i'm still a little lost on the difference.

Comment: What, the two linked examples and linked tutorial aren't enough?

Comment: I just need help on how could i get the song inside the "clip" to play. the song name is "Song1" and it's in the same folder.. how would i do that?

Comment: `getClass().getResource("Song1")` (but shouldn't it have an extension)

Comment: Sorry i'm kinda new to java so i don't know too much.. So can you explain what you mean a bit more.

Comment: *"So can you explain what you mean a bit more"* which part?  Replace `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sounds/Maid with the Flaxen Hair.wav")` with the `getClass().getResource("Song1")`?